# Tag [micromax-unite] needs a wiki

Tags: discussion

I noticed a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114166/how-to-get-back-google-play-services-on-micromax-a106-running-lollipop) which popped up in Active tab few minutes ago, and was tagged with [micromax-unite](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/micromax-unite)

Looking at all the questions in that tag, I see that most of them are related to the device "Micromax Unite 2 A106" with one exception of "Micromax Unite 3 Q372".

I think a tag wiki is definitely needed now to signify the purpose this tag serves, preferably intended to serve a series of devices under a common brand.

<sup>I don't know anything about this device, or I could have tried suggesting the wiki.</sup>

Comment: GSMArena mentions multiple devices with that name, e.g. [Micromax A106 Unite 2](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a106_unite_2-6382.php) (see [these Google Search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Micromax+Unite+site%3Agsmarena.com)).

Comment: @Izzy Thank you. I think I must work hard on my search queries for Google. And I now have made changes into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the tag is fine, and for those few questions more diversification is not justified. A tag-wiki excerpt could mention the tag is for all devices of the "Micromax Unite" brand, while the wiki itself could go into more detail.